# Mysql average but different

Tags: mysql, sql, moving-average

I get stuck on  problem with an average in Mysql and have no idea how to proceed. An easy example. I have a table which looks like this:

```
DATTIME              VALUE
2013-06-01 00:15:00  10
2013-06-01 00:30:00  12
2013-06-01 00:45:00  11
2013-06-01 01:00:00  15
2013-06-01 01:15:00  13
2013-06-01 01:30:00  14
2013-06-01 01:45:00  11
2013-06-01 02:00:00  10
2013-06-01 02:15:00  10
2013-06-01 02:30:00  12
2013-06-01 02:45:00  11
2013-06-01 03:00:00  15
...
```

Now I want an average for the last 2 hours from the "perspective" of each row. So in the line with the time "02:15:00" I would like to have the average from "00:15:00" til "02:15:00" in the line "02:30:00" the average from "01:30:00" til "02:30:00". All tries with floor and similar functions havent brought the expected result.

Could someone points me into the right direction. Probably I'm on a wrong way...

Thank in advance.

Cheers,
Uwe

Answer (score 2):

```
select  *
,       (
        select  avg(value)
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.dattime between 
                    yt1.dattime - interval 2 hour
                    and yt1.dattime
        ) as LastTwoHourAverage
from    YourTable yt1
```

If the above is slow, you can try this variant:

```
select  yt1.dattime
,       yt1.value
,       avg(yt2.value) as LastTwoHourAverage
from    YourTable yt1
left join
        YourTable yt2
on      yt2.dattime between 
            yt1.dattime - interval 2 hour
            and yt1.dattime
```

Comment: Andomar: Perfect, thank you. One additional question. To keep it simple I had created a short example. In my table date and time are in seperated columns. I have tried yt2.unix_timestamp(DATUM+" "+UHRZEIT) between... but this will not work of course. How can I solve that error?

Comment: select  *
,       (
        select  avg(ACTMSU), concat( DATUM, " ", UHRZEIT ) as dattime1
        from    smf70 yt2
        where   yt2.dattime1 between 
                    yt1.dattime - interval 4 hour
                    and yt1.dattime
        ) as LastTwoHourAverage
from    smf70 yt1 where yt1.DATUM="2012-12-23" and yt1.UHRZEIT>"04:00:00"

Comment: In MySQL, use `concat(str1, str2, str3, ...)` to add strings. You can use [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the concatenation of two fields to a date.

Comment: select  * 
,       (
        select  avg(yt2.ACTMSU) 
        from    smf70 as yt2
        where   STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( yt2.DATUM, " ", yt2.UHRZEIT ) , '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i' ) between 
                    STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( yt1.DATUM, " ", yt1.UHRZEIT ) , '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i' ) - interval 4 hour
                    and STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( yt1.DATUM, " ", yt1.UHRZEIT ) , '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i' )
        ) as LastTwoHourAverage
from    smf70 yt1 where yt1.DATUM="2012-12-23" and yt1.UHRZEIT>"04:00:00"

Comment: @user1478108, I would make sure you have an index on the date/time field in question to help optimize the query.  If there is not one, you would be hosed on performance... Also, as you do find solutions to your answers, be sure to click the checkmark next to the answers so others know it is resolved, and others looking for similar will know what did work for you.